# How do I convert this form_tag helper into a simple_form_for call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

This is the HTML I am trying to produce:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
   <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
        </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
</div>
```

This is my vanilla Rails form helper:

```
    <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                <%= form_tag(dashboard_index_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form", :class => "navbar-form navbar-left") do %>
                   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search videos", :class => "form-control" %>
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <%= submit_tag "", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                 </span>

                                <% end %>
             </div><!-- /input-group -->
     </div> <!-- //col-lg-3 -->
```

This is what this looks like:

[image: Broken Search Form]

Whereas what I am trying to achieve is this:

[image: Desired Search Form]

Generated from this:

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/search-box

I would like to generate the above HTML, using `simple_form_for`, rather than the `form_tag` helper.

So I have `simple_form` installed. How do I convert this `form_tag` into a `simple_form_for` call?

```
<%= form_tag(dashboard_index_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form", :class => "navbar-form navbar-left") do %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `form_tag` also. Try below code :

```
<%= form_tag(dashboard_index_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form", :class => "navbar-form navbar-left") do %>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search videos", :class => "form-control" %>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <%= button_tag "", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default", type: "button" do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        <% end %>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div> <!-- //col-lg-3 -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm. You, sir...are worth every point of bounty I had to giveaway!

Answer (score 0):

Form_tag do not generate an input html class and submit_tag neither a button html class, and maybe css code expect this class, try with button_tag

Comment: What would be the equivalent `simple_form_for` for that `form_tag`?

Comment: I think that will be dificult use form_tag, maybe is better option use AJAX to call your controller.